# Stringbuilder and arrays

Tags: c#, .net

I have an array e.g. string[] ccsplit.

I want to add all of these into a string, so I use stringbuilder:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string str in ccsplit)
{
    builder.Append(str);
}
```

But the only problem is that I don't want the string ccsplit[0] to be added to the stringbuilder, how could I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can start the index at 1 all the time and append it to stringbuilder.

```
for(int i=1; i<lengthOfArray;i++)
{
    //Do your stuff.
}
```

Answer (score 10):

There's not even a need to use a StringBuilder or a loop.

```
 string result = String.Concat(ccsplit.Skip(1));
```

Will do the job. You do need Fx 4 or later.

Answer (score 4):

One Line Answer

```
string str = string.Join("", ccsplit.Skip(1).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can use Linq, you could use the Skip extension method:

```
foreach (string str in ccsplit.Skip(1)) 
{
    builder.Append(str);
}
```

or, without Linq:

```
for (int i = 1; i < ccsplit.Length; i++) {
    builder.Append(ccsplit[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Skip() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx

```
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string str in ccsplit.Skip(1))
        {
            builder.Append(str);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use LINQ to concat all strings:

```
String result = ccsplit.Skip(1).Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1 + s2);
```

**Edit**: Here's a version that uses `StringBuilder`:

```
String result = ccsplit.Skip(1).Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
                (sb, str) => sb.Append(str),
                (sb) => sb.ToString());
```

[Enumerable.Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548744.aspx)

Comment: Using LINQ for that is like using a cannon to shoot flies :P KISS

Comment: What reason to use here Aggregate, if we can just Join or Concat? Also, no reason to use StringBuilder here, Concat is already optimized for full-length result string.

Comment: @Harm: String.Concat is only optimized(using a StringBuilder internally) if you're not concatenating in a loop. Ok, i've missed the simple String.Join :)

Answer (score 2):

This is how you could do it without LINQ.

```
for (var i = 1; i < ccsplit.Length; i++){
    builder.Append(ccsplit[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`using System.Linq;`

...

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); 
foreach (string str in ccsplit.Skip(1)) 
{ 
    builder.Append(str); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a `string` in the end, so just use appropriate `string.Join` overload instead of `StringBuilder` and a loop:

```
string combined = string.Join(string.Empty, ccsplit, 1, ccsplit.Length - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop :

```
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 1; i < ccsplit.Length; i++)
    {
         builder.Append(ccsplit[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); 
for (int ccsplitIndex = 1; ccsplitIndex < ccsplit.Length; ccsplitIndex++) 
{ 
    builder.Append(ccsplit[ccsplitIndex]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the foreach by a for starting the index at 1 instead of 0

```
for (int i = 1; i <= ccsplit.Length-1; i++)
{
   builder.Append(ccsplit[i]);
}
```